# Standard Master Page for new projects company wide

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

We are standardizing on Visual Studio 2010 for application development, along with implementing Team Foundation Server. What we are curious about is how can we setup a master page (i.e. site master) that will contain items we want on every page such as site navigation and company logo so that anytime someone in the company at any location creates a new project we can ensure they are using this site master page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom Project template.

- You simply start a new project.
- Add/modify as much as you need.
- Use the "Export Template" wizard from the File menu.

This will create a zip file which will need to be installed on each desktop's copy of Visual Studio ("Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates" usually), but once there will allow the user to select File>New Project and select "Corporate Standard Wesite" as the project type (for example).

Comment: Thanks, sounds like we can't make it a totally automated solution where by default it will use these master pages. However we'll have a code review team and this will be one of the things they will verify before releasing the product into production.